# Sprinkles Animation

Tags: modeling, particles, geometry-nodes

I've been working on a project, using Blender, but unfortunately I am stuck on one part:[image][image]
Is there any way to achieve this using blender? What basically I want is that sprinkles come quickly, the ones that touch the cake cube stick to it, and the rest fly into the background. I'm confused about what to use for this, and also, are particle simulations possible in geometry nodes?

Edit: This is the reference video I want it like on the cube from 0:16 to 0:19 https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=iVjOD7fRRxs

Thanks in advance.

Comment: i think a lot of people could answer your question, if it would be clear what you want. I would recommend that you improve your question so that it is crystal clear what you mean and what effect you want. A link to a video with that effect would help a lot.

Comment: e.g. what is not clear: should one or several sticks touch the cube? what do you mean by come quickly ? from random positions, from left, right...!? and what do you mean by fly into the background? to minus y? or away from the camera? we can/want only help if we know what you want, because else we invest time for a solution and your answer will be: no, that's not what i meant. And nobody wants to waste time...

Comment: @Chris would it be okay if I attached the video?

Comment: Of course!! Just do it

Comment: @Chris I've attached it.

Comment: Move your particles in a direction, add a raycast with the same direction, stop movement on hit position.

Comment: @quellenform Can you post an answer explained in detail if it's not inconvenient? Since I'm a little inexperienced in particles/physics/geometry/ nodes only.

Comment: I was thinking just animate it in reverse - take the finished particle system and separate it out, throw them off of the donut, offset keyframes by a random amount and then render the image sequence in reverse.

Comment: You can add more particles which miss or bounce off

Comment: @AllenSimpson can you explain it in detail in an answer, since I'm really not understanding how to do this (since its a cube I need you can demonstrate it on the default cube if you can)

Comment: @quellenform Okay thanks

Comment: @AllenSimpson I'm just curious. What is the advantage of the reversed animation compared to just killing emitter particles on hit? In the video, half of the sprinkles fly by and don't stick to the donut anyway.

Comment: @Blunder Only that you could guarantee the end state of your object, may or may not be desired

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here just a short sketch of what I would use (*geometry nodes* only):

[image]

Essentially, I'm doing something here that Geometry Nodes probably weren't designed for, but it's still fun.

- First, I create a simple mesh on which I distribute points.
- Then I move these points in a certain direction. To make them start with a time delay, I used the technique described in more detail here: [How to Randomly Delay Animation for Geometry Node Instances?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/261392/145249)
- At the same time I use the node `Raycast` with the same direction as *Ray Direction*. So that I can stop the rotation of the particles later at a certain angle, I pass a randomly generated value here as *Attribute*.
- Next, I create a random vector here that serves as my rotation axis.
- As soon as the particles hit the cube I stop the rotation and the movement.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot! You can edit your answer if you want, but this is also enough for me. Again, thanks very very much!

Answer (score 5):

Probably the most simple solution is using default particles:

For donut, enable **Collision** and **Kill particles** in collusion settings:

[image]

In particles enable display dead:

[image]

This will kill particles on collision and stop its motion

[image]

Comment: Yes, I like that solution! How would you handle the rotation of the particles here?

Comment: You can make rotation in particle settings, and it stops on killing.

Comment: @Crantisz Doesn't killing the particles make them disappear?

Comment: Yes, until you don't set display **Dead**.