# How to copy objects with delayed keyframes?

Tags: keyframes

I made the red cube move for 100 frames

I made a blue cube by duplicating a red cube. And since I moved the keyframe back, the blue cube moves after 20 frames

[image]

But this work takes two steps.

1. Duplicating  2. Moving Keyframes

But I want to give delayed keyframes to many cubes, so I want to know how to easily do two steps at once.

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Probably this could work ...

- *Duplicate* node - set number of instances
- *Multiply* node - set time offset (delay in frames)
- *Integer* node - set animationn length (of one instance in frames)
- *Map Range* node - *To Min* = start location, *To Max* = end location (meters)

[image]
[image]
Based on [answer](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/261392/2214) by @quellenform

[image]

Answer (score 2):

The *Nonlinear Animation* editor is made for that:

- Duplicate your cube
- Select a cube. In the *Dope Sheet*, switch to *Action Editor*, click on the *Push Down* button to push the action into the *Nonlinear Animation* editor:

[image]

- In the *Nonlinear Animation* editor, move the strip:

[image]

It works fine for tens of cube, if you have hundreds of cube, maybe consider *Geometry Nodes*?

Comment: What makes a difference between Q/A workflow? I mean - it is also 2 steps.

Comment: Yes but with his solution you'll end up with tens of actions, it seems more convenient to work with the NLA. I guess the only other solution is to do it with Geometry Nodes, but I don't know them enough

Comment: Ah ... I forgot, when PushDown the action is reused in duplicated object ... yes it is convenient :) Thanks

Comment: I didn't test it, but seems to be related https://github.com/mrachinskiy/commotion

Comment: Oh ok thanks i'll take a look at it