# Offset and time-scale Armature animation in Geometry nodes instances

Tags: animation, geometry-nodes

Is it possible to randomly offset and change speed of animated assets that are instanced on GN points?
I've found [a tutorial on Youtube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pbxXrDHSDsI&ab_channel=GarageFarm.NETAcademy) in which author duplicates assets and node groups each time to create offsets which seams like a not very effective thing to do.

Attaching my scene that have 2 animations:

- a GN-driven movement forward for creatures that can be easily randomised by adding to `Scene Time` node;
- an Armature-based movement of a creature that I'm unable to control — this is the animation I want to offset/timescale

[image]

[image]

Comment: Does this solve your problem? https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/260744/

Comment: Hi @quellenform, thank you for reply. Unfortunately it doesn't because in that example the animation is driven by the scene time (the animation is procedural in GN) and in my case instances use Armature for animation

Comment: hm I just realised that my scene/screenshot might be confusing because there's a procedural animation for the instances to move forward. The question is about offsetting the animation of the Armature animation, not the forward movement. I've updated my question, hopefully it's more clear

Comment: Geometry Nodes can't evaluate an object deformed (or moved) by armature in a different way, tjan it is currently deformed/moved on the given frame. So I see two workarounds: 1) "bake" all possible poses into a single frame as separate objects, load that into a collection and now you can choose one of them form *Collection Info* node. 2) Reproduce your entire armature in Geometry Nodes, so that you can deform / move stuff within Geonodes… The first solution is "destructive", you would need to e.g. run a Python script after each change. Second solution is probably very hard.

Comment: @SergeyKritskiy: as Markus already wrote: GN isn't really helpful here. If i were you, i would use animation nodes which has python script nodes with which you can much easier control bones and armatures. So i think your tool is the wrong choice (maybe in the future, but as it is now, it has no support for armatures at all)