# How can I move a bunch of objects or instances sequentially in timeline?

Tags: animation

I need ideas for making the screws animation like in the video.
https://youtu.be/leosVYDGb-Q?t=14

Certainly, moving a few objects using a keyframe is not a challenge, I can add a keyframe to one object and copy it to others with different start points, but if the quantity is big, I don't see this as a proper way.

Is the blender has a function that can move a collection of objects or instances to a certain position orderly in the timeline?

I see a tutorial of an animation-node addon that could do the exact right thing I have mentioned but seems like the addon is not maintained, thus not supporting Blender 3.4 or 3.3.
Thanks!
[image]

Comment: commotion (add-on) does work and does exactly that. And of course procedural add-ons can do this as well like animation nodes (works for sure, i am using it, so either you are downloading the wrong version or you do something wrong installing it), sverchok. Even geometry nodes can do this

Comment: so maybe you should ask another question? how to install animation add-on? and maybe tell us what error occurs...but open another question for that, because you should only ask 1 question here. You can open as many questions as you like.

Comment: You can use Geometry nodes to define this behavior as shown here.
https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/260744/how-to-randomly-delay-animation-for-geometry-node-instances

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @Chris mentioned in the comment section of this question, I solved this problem by using Commotion Addon.
Never knew it exists before, thank you very much @Chris.

This is the addon page on GitHub.
https://github.com/mrachinskiy/commotion

Comment: Thanks! That is the right addon I needed. It's a great addon.