# Time offset in Geometry Nodes?

Tags: geometry-nodes

I'm looking for a way to time things that happen in a geometry node setup.

The idea is to have things happen sequentially. I've seen `Scene Time` but can't figure out how to use it to count frames for like a holdout timer.

Example: I have a rotation (Simulation Zone) that should be generated after the buildup Sim Zone and a finishing setup that should be created after it.

```
Setups |  (intro) > (rotation) > (ending)
Frames |    48f        120f        48f
```

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/260744/how-to-randomly-delay-animation-for-geometry-node-instances

Comment: Might this [Tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=f1O_yOk9dtI&ab_channel=PIXXO3D) be helpful?

Comment: @harry-mckenzie Thanks, that helped with another issue I had.

Comment: @e3-productions indeed it is. Now I have another option for timed builds. Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Every simulation zone starts at frame $1$, therefore You can't chain simulation zones. Instead, use a single simulation zone, with multiple layers, and a switch - or multiple switches as I show in the example:

[image]

[image]

Comment: That's genius! Clean and flexible. Thank you!