# Simulation nodes: Create an instance, scale it up, scale it down, and then dissapear

Tags: transforms, mathematics, simulation-nodes

I am trying to create a simulation that, at a certain point in time, creates a point, attache an instance there, and then scale it from 0 to 1. And upon reaching scale 1, goes back to scale 0. And at this point, it disappears. I can make mesth to points, intance to point, then create the point inside the simulation node, and I can give an age to the point, so it dissapears. My main concern is the scale up and down. I think I can do this with the sine math node, with some fine tuning, but I would like to be able to do it with conditionals. That is, *if the instance scale is greater than 1, instead of getting bigger, it gets smaller.* I know this can be done (at least I think so) with the repeat zone, but I would like to know how to do it in the simulation nodes. Thank you so much.

Comment: i will help you with that if you provide a blend file how far you have come and that i don't waste my time building it from ground up. And remember: you want help for free from us in our spare time -> so you should make it as easy and fast as possible to help you. thx.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Time offset in Geometry Nodes?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/299641/time-offset-in-geometry-nodes)

Comment: This would not necessarily involve a simulation.. as described, that could just be, say,  a  mapped  _Float Curve_  on the time. Can you describe the desired _effect_, more precisely, rather than the method, so as to avoid possible [XY](https://xyproblem.info/) ?

Comment: Hi! The desired effect is to create an effect where one instance is created, when it's created it scales from 0 to 1, and when it gets there, it scales back from 1 to 0. When the scale is 0, it's deleted. It can be achieved with math, using for example the sine, but what I wanted was to use booleans (if scale => 1, then scale it down back to 0).

Comment: I achieved this using the Swith node, that can work with float numbers, so it's as easy as using a math node (greater than) as a contraint. When the scale of the instance is 1, it scales by 0.9, so it just shrinks. I'm still working on improve the method, since I find it really useful and straight forward for animation within the geo and sim nodes. Just for begginers like myself, I recommend to check very well the options within the nodes, since my problem was that I thought that the swith node only work with geometry. Anyway, thank you for your time!