# How can I animate these instances falling into position in a random order using geometry nodes?

Tags: animation, geometry-nodes

Here are a bunch of instanced cubes.
[image]
I am trying to get them to 'fall' above into this position using geo nodes. But I want them to fall in a random order.

My theory was to first have some way of randomly selecting the instances with a set position node. Then somehow giving each instance different information when to begin moving. Along the way, I hoped to find some way of driving the whole animation as well. Any good solutions to this?

Here is my current node tree:
[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/260744/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the simplest solution I found:

[image]

With this, all I have to do is key frame the black position in the color ramp connected to the noise node. The math (multiply) node after wards simply raises the height to the position I want. It will always end in the same position (as long as the value in the math node is +). I also experimented with using different outputs from the Spline Parameter node as a factor for the noise. This falls short of having more detailed control of each instance, but serves my purpose.

[image]